# Confusing File structure of PhpFox

Tags: module, phpfox

I am wondering how can I modify the layout of the featured members module? I can see that part of it is in the template folder of the module in file

```
module/user/template/<mytemplate>/block/featured.html.php
```

and some part I find in

```
file/cache/template_user_template_default_block_fetaured.html.php
```

Does that mean I need to make changes in this second file too? If yes then it will reflect on all themes.

Can anyone explain the PhpFox file and folder structure?

Answer (score 3):

You just change the first one 
module/user/template//block/featured.html.php

Second one is cached file, if you change first one then second one also be updated because
second one is generated from first one .

if you want to know the file structure then know how to create the module first 
just go to this link : http://www.phpfox.com/kb/article/144/creating-your-first-add-on/

more :
http://www.phpfox.com/kb/article/263/knowledgebase-article-listing/

Comment: https://web.archive.org/web/20120114045710/http://www.phpfox.com/kb/article/144/creating-your-first-add-on - It's only available historically :(

Answer (score 0):

As [SKG](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8677229/2151300) mentioned, the first file is the original file and the second file is cached file.

But if you modify the first file, the second file will NOT be updated until you clear the chache of your website.

You can clear the cache in two ways.

1. Visit http://www.domain.tld/admincp/maintain/cache/ and click the "Clear All" button.
2. Connect to your ftp folder and open /file/cache folder. Delete all the files (except index.html) manually.